# Plotting a curve on MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I was wondering on how I could plot this curve that's called spiral in my code down below. Such curve depends on x3(t) and x4(t) and all the parameters are positive numbers.

```matlab
syms t ;

rf = 4;%%%insert rf as input
m=2;
b=1;
M=m+b;
d=0.1;
k=1;
g = M*d/(2*(m*b));%gamma
w = sqrt(k*M/(m*b));%omega
delta=sqrt(abs(g^2-w^2));

x3plus=-(1/w^2*b)*exp(-g*t)*cos(delta*t)-(g/w^2*b)*exp(-g*t)*sin(delta*t)+(1/w^2*b);

x4plus=diff(x3plus,t);

spiralplus = (x3plus-(1/w^2*b))^2+((x4plus+g*(x3plus-(1/w^2*b)))/delta)^2-(1/w^4*b^2)*(1+(g^2/delta^2))*exp(-2*g*t)==0;

fimplicit3(spiralplus)
```

I tried 'fplot' and 'plot' but I kept getting this: 'Input must be a function handle or symbolic function'. I also tried 'fimplicit3' but it returns an empty graphic.

Comment: How have you declared `t` in your code? It would be best to have complete code (ie define all variables), so we can run the code ourselves. See [mre].

Comment: Yes, I set t as symbolic variable.

Comment: `spiralplus` is an equation, do I see this right? You probably need to `solve` it first before you can plot it.

Comment: It's an equation but it's like an implicit function you know? Like I want to plot : x^2+y^2-t=0,  then I should get like a family of circles, right?

Comment: Did you try using the function `solve` as I suggested?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit3.html), `fimplicit3` is a numeric function, not symbolic. You’ll have to rephrase your symbolic expression as a numeric function, vectorized (see the liked help page for details on how to do this).

Comment: I tried 'solve' and it didn't return any result.

Comment: For what concerns your 'fimplicit3' insight, after rephrasing my curve as a numeric vector, I get this error :                                                                                              Error using nargin                                                                                                               
Argument must be either a character vector, string scalar, or a function handle.

Comment: Check the matlabFunction[https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.matlabfunction.html] function, that converts symbolic expressions to anonymous functions. Perhaps this can help you plot the implicit function, if it was properly calculated.

Comment: However, the definition of your implicit function is strange. Since `x3plus` and `x4plus` depends on the independent parameter `t`, your anonymous function depens only on `t`. You would typically plot this function as `fplot(spiralplus)`. So there is no need to `solve` it for the desired variables. If you want to create the curve as function of `x3` and `x4`, you must define the implicit function `f(x3,x4) = 0`, as in `spiral = @(x3,x4) ...'. Then you can call `fimplicit(spiral)`. You shouldn't call `fimplicit3`, because this assumes your functions depends on 3 variables (which is not the case

Comment: when I run the question in the code MATLAB returns no error. What MATLAB version do you use? Also the 3D graph is empty, may be the way data is generated?

Comment: I'm using the 2020 version. Do you think it's obsolete?